# Java String not replacing with hashmap values

Tags: java, string, replace, hashmap

```
   for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {

                String delimiter = "**";
                result = result.replace(delimiter + entry.getKey() + delimiter, entry.getValue());

            }
```

result is my string to be replaced by hashmap values.
Here string  (result variable) is returning as itself not replacing any value.
Please any one have suggestions ?

---

*From comment*

My hashmap contains,

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
map.put("Rid", serviceBooking.getId().toString()); 
map.put("Rname", customer.getName()); 
map.put("Rnic", "");
```

Comment: This should work, assuming that the string actually contains keys from the map surrounded by "**" delimiters.  Post the contents of the map, and some example strings.

Comment: could you please clarify your question?

Comment: @user1285148: Did you try debugging or write a test to focus on the problem..

Comment: My hashmap contains, HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                            map.put("*Rid*", serviceBooking.getId().toString());
                                            map.put("*Rname*", customer.getName());
                                            map.put("*Rnic*", "");

Comment: Jayan, result is a String variable that contains some text. I want to replace some text uisng values in the hashmap

Comment: Wyzard,<tr><td  align='center'><b  style='font-size:18px;'>Ref ID: Rid</b> </td>
Example string is above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm OK Here's a working, executable example:

```
// sample input
String input = "abcd **Rid** efgh";

// a small map
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Rid","VALUE");

// the loop that replaces the **Rid** substring
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry:map.entrySet()){
  input = input.replace("**"+entry.getKey()+"**", entry.getValue());
  System.out.println(input);
}
```

It prints

```
abcd VALUE efgh
```

Comment: In your case its completely working. My input is string generated from HTML file is it a problem ?

Comment: No, it isn't. A string is a string. If it doesn't replace anything, then no `**<map-key>**` is in the String, that you use for the replacement operation. Use a debugger or print `map` *and* `result` to the console and have a closer look.

Comment: Andreas_D,I printed the map and see, it is printing all the key values as it should be, what would be the case ?

Comment: Then, only other reason: `result` does not have the expected value when you enter the for loop. (and, let's remember that the replacement operation is case sensitive)

Comment: Andreas_D , can i have your email , then i can send you the all code if you ok with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Either your `HashMap` is empty, or the original string doesn't contain anything corresponding to the keys in the map, or you wrote two asterisks where you meant one, or you didn't escape it/them when you needed to, or ...

Impossible to improve on that without seeing the original string and the contents of the map.

Comment: HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                            map.put("*Rid*", serviceBooking.getId().toString());
                                            map.put("*Rname*", customer.getName());
                                            map.put("*Rnic*", "");

Comment: @user1285148 Good, that's half of what I said was missing.

Comment: I removeed delimiter = "**";.BUt still problem is there

Comment: @user1285148 You still haven't shown us what the original string looks like. I've asked for it twice now.

Comment: EJP ,<tr><td align='center'><b style='font-size:18px;'>Ref ID: Rid</b> </td> Example string is above